# Приложения автопостинг на jave

Tags: java

Всем добрый день) Прошу сразу не ругать меня и не оскорблять за столь тупые вопросы) Я новичок в JAVA и хочется что-то практиковать. Очень хочется написать приложение которое будет писать посты в группу ВК(что-то типа автопостинга новостей). Но информации по JAva не густо, все пишут на с, на питоне и на php. И возникает вопрос, на этих языках проще это реализовать или это предпочтение?
Может у кто-то встречал какие-то новости по написанию такого приложения на Jave? Или кто-то подскажет с чего начать) Какой-то алгоритм? Хоть что-то)))

Answer (score 1):

Краткая структура, как я вижу:

1. Подготовка контента.
2. Авторизация программы\скрипта для работы с VK API.
3. Выполнение запросов через API.
4. Профит.

Лучше выбрать скриптовые языки, которые можно запускать на shared хостинге. PHP и python хорошие.

Это моё имхо, я сам junior, буду рад критике :).

Answer (score 1):

У вк есть довольно неплохое api. [линк](https://vk.com/dev/openapi)

Так что постить можно посредством POST GET запросов. Как отправить запрос на ява думаю инфа в гугле есть. Так же чтобы вк принял запрос понадобится [токен](https://vk.com/dev/oauth_gettoken) и возможно [ключ приложения](https://vk.com/dev/access_token).

Алгоритм будет примерно такой.

1. Получаем ключ приложения
2. Получаем токен
3. Авторизуемся вк
4. Отправляем запрос, указав ключ, токен, группу для поста и текст
5. Если все прошло удачно то увидим наш пост